# Error when using QueryDefs to return Recordset

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm trying to access a query using VBA code.  I think I've done it this way 100 times.  My code (on a command button) starts like this:

```
Dim rstDocCount As Recordset

Set rstDocCount = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DocCount").OpenRecordset

rst.MoveFirst
```

I get this error message:

> Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters.  Expected 1.

The `Set rstDocCount` line is highlighted yellow.

What am I doing wrong?  The only parameter should be the name of the query and I clearly have that.

Comment: Open the query in the database window. It will show you which field is mispelled or which parameter is missing.

Comment: There's no problem with the query.  I am able to open it while the form is open, from which this code is running.  The query has a parameter Forms!Boxing!BoxID (Boxing is the current form).  My suspicion is that vba can't read that field for some reason.  I found that if I replace the query with other queries that use a parameter from the Boxing form, I get the same error.  If I replace it with a simpler query there is no problem.  So I think I need to instead make the query show every record, then loop through them to get to the one that matches the BoxID on my form.

Comment: You just need to set the parameter. See below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need:

```
Dim rstDocCount As Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("DocCount")

    qdf.Parameters("Forms!Boxing!BoxID") = Forms!Boxing!BoxID 
    Set rstDocCount = qdf.OpenRecordset

    rstDocCount.MoveFirst
```

Answer (score 1):

"*The only parameter should be the name of the query and I clearly have that.*"

The `OpenRecordset` method accepts 3 parameters: `Type`; `Options`; and `LockEdit`.  However all 3 of those parameters are optional, so the "*Too few parameters*" error isn't about `OpenRecordset` parameters.

Instead, as Remou pointed out, your `QueryDef` includes something (frequently a field expression) the db engine can't find in the query's source table.  In that situation, it treats the missing *something* as a parameter and requires a value for that parameter.

Comment: See my comment above replying to Remou.